# Don't show element if on top of main content

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there a general way to check if a content is on top of another element? For example:

In [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReYrXv) page, the element `.ads` is not on top of the `.content`, therefore it's not a problem. But in [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReYagX) page, it's interfering the reader, so it shouldn't be seem.

It's important to notice that I'm looking for a general way to do that, I don't know what is the main element, or it's size, only the `ads` element.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any way to do it, and there aren't any other questions on SO about that, so I couldn't provide what I've tried since it seems impossible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, the piece in which you don't know what `.ads` might be overlapping is the real crux, I think.  You can do some fancy coding to determine if two elements are occupying the same space, but to do it for _all_ elements would be challenging-- for instance, it will always be overlapping the element that contains it, no?  Can you clearly define your requirements in this regard?  I think doing that would be crucial to being able to code this solution.

Comment: The idea would be to only avoid siblings or children of siblings. As you said, I wouldn't want to avoid a parent, otherwise, it would be always overlapping.

Comment: Are you sure that that is a complete characterization?  What if `.ads` is at `body>.sidebar>.ads` and there is also `body > .main > .content`?  You would probably want to make sure that `.ads` wasn't somehow overlapping `.content`, but `.content` couldn't be characterized as a "sibling or child of a sibling".  Unless you have a reasonable guarantee that such an overlap is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no DOM method that provides this functionality. You can write a function that checks if two elements are overlapping. If they are, then check the CSS properties of both to infer that one is on top of the other. This can get you started:

```
function areOverlapping(elem1, elem2) {
  const rect1 = elem1.getBoundingClientRect();
  const rect2 = elem2.getBoundingClientRect();

  return !(rect2.left > rect1.right || 
           rect2.right < rect1.left || 
           rect2.top > rect1.bottom ||
           rect2.bottom < rect1.top);
}

const ads = document.querySelector('.ads');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');

if (areOverlapping(ads, content)) {
  const style1 = window.getComputedStyle(ads);
  const style2 = window.getComputedStyle(content);

  // Here you can check CSS position, z-index, display, etc.
  // to infer that one is on top of the other.
  //
  // e.g. if one is position:fixed and the other is static,
  // you know the fixed is on top of the static due to overlap.
}
```